# pytorch - per sample gradients of network's output wrt input

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, backpropagation

I would like to compute the second derivative of the network output wrt input and I need access to the output per sample. These derivative is later used to form loss function.

Following Pytorch’s tutorial (https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/per_sample_grads.html), I managed to construct some simple code:

```
u_pred = self.forward(inputs)

def compute_grad(u_in, x_in): 
   grad_x     = torch.autograd.grad(u_in.unsqueeze(0), x_in, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(u_in.unsqueeze(0)), retain_graph=True, create_graph=True, only_inputs=True)[0]
   grad_xx    = torch.autograd.grad(grad_x.unsqueeze(0), x_in, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(u_in.unsqueeze(0)), retain_graph=True, create_graph=True, only_inputs=True)[0]
   return grad_xx

sample_grads = [compute_grad(u_pred[i], inputs) for i in range(bs)]
ample_grads = zip(*sample_grads)
sample_grads = [torch.stack(shards) for shards in sample_grads]
sample_grads = torch.stack(sample_grads)
```

It works, but it is super slow.
I also attempted to use vmap, but it does not seem work with adagrad.

Does anybody have a recommendation on how to speedup these computations?